# Calling script in elevated mode with more than one named argument

Tags: powershell, arguments

**Test.ps1**

```
Param (
    [String]$CountryCode,
    [String]$FilesPath,
    [String]$KeepassDatabase,
    [String]$KeepassKeyFile,
    [String]$EventLog,
    [String]$EventSource
)

Write-Host 'Ok' -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host $PSBoundParameters
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
```

The goal is to call the script with named parameters in elevated mode. When using named parameters without `$Credential`, it works fine. The window pops up and the word `Ok` is displayed:

```
$StartParams = @{
    ArgumentList = "-File `"Test.ps1`" -verb `"runas`" -FilesPath `"S:\Files`" -CountryCode `"XXX`""
}
Start-Process powershell @StartParams
```

When I add the `Credential` argument it also pops-up but I can't see anything:

```
$StartParams = @{
    Credential   = Get-Credential
        ArgumentList = "-File `"Test.ps1`" -verb `"runas`" -FilesPath `"S:\Files`" -CountryCode `"XXX`""
}
Start-Process powershell @StartParams
```

Am I missing something super obvious here? Even when using the same credentials as the logged on user, I can't see the text.

Comment: `-verb runas` doesn't belong in the argumentlist. It's a parameter for `Start-Process`, not `PowerShell.exe`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but then it complains it doesn't belong to the parameter set. Did it work for you?

Comment: You could also just use `#requires -RunAsAdministrator` in your script instead of trying to re-invoke it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify an absolute path to the file. The new PowerShell-process (which will run as admin) doesn't run in the same working directory as your current session.

Try:

```
$StartParams = @{
    FilePath = "powershell.exe"
    Credential   = Get-Credential
    Verb = "RunAs"
    ArgumentList = "-File `"c:\temp\Test.ps1`" -FilesPath `"S:\Files`" -CountryCode `"XXX`""
}
Start-Process @StartParams
```

If you only know the relative path, use `Resolve-Path` to convert it. Ex:

```
ArgumentList = "-NoExit -File `"$(Resolve-Path test.ps1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path)`" -FilesPath `"S:\Files`" -CountryCode `"XXX`""
```

You should also look into string format or here-string so you can avoid escaping every double quote. It makes your life easier:

```
#Using here-string (no need to escape double quotes)
ArgumentList = @"
-NoExit -File "$(Resolve-Path test.ps1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path)" -FilesPath "S:\Files" -CountryCode "XXX"
"@

#Using string format
ArgumentList = '-NoExit -File "{0}" -FilesPath "{1}" -CountryCode "{2}"' -f (Resolve-Path test.ps1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path), "S:\Files", "XXX"
```

Comment: I found another issue too: In case parameters are incorrectly called, please check that the script you call is not having `[CmdLetBinding()]` at the top. Also, the `ArgumentList` for  `Start-Process` needs to start with `"-File ""$ScriptPath"" -verb runas" + $Arguments`.

Comment: Why do you think cmdletbinding is bad? Arguments for the script needs to come after `-File ...`. You can have parameters for `powershell.exe` prior to it (ex `-noexit`). Verb is not a part of argumentlist, it's a parameter for `start-process`.